# Find the time complexity of the algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I think it is log(logn) because the cycle repeats log(logn) times...

```
j=1;
i=2;
while (i <= n) do {
    B[j] = A[i];
    j = j + 1;
    i = i * i;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it is `O(lg(lg n))` where `lg` stands for base 2 logarithm.

The reason being that the sequence of values of `i` is subject to the rule `i = prev(i) * prev(i)`, which turns out to be 2, 2^2, 2^4, 2^8, ... for steps 1, 2, 3, 4, .... In other words, the value of `i` after `k` iterations is `2^{2^k}`.

Thus, the loop will stop as soon as `2^{2^k} > n` or `k > lg(lg(n))` (Just take `lg` twice to both sides of the inequality. The inequality remains valid because `lg` is an increasing function.)